# Fails to SSH into GitHub with ProxyCommand Configured

Tags: github, ssh, proxy

I am trying to use ProxyCommand in the .ssh config files so that all SSH connections are routed into a localhost port. I am trying to clone some repos from my GitHub account. Below is what I got when trying to SSH into the GitHub SSH server.

[Github SSH Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXC61.png)

I think the error is due to the fact that I am using ProxyCommand, as other posts have shown that it results in obscure errors shown in the image. For your reference, below is my SSH config.

[SSH Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wH2.png)

I tried to clone the repo without the proxy and it works. But I need to use SSH over proxy.